# How to authorize importing an Azure Storage Account into Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, authorization, azure-storage-account, terraform-import

I have a storage account created inside a resource group and I want to import both of them into a `.tfstate` file to be managed by Terraform. The Resource group gets imported fine, but the storage account import command gives me an error saying that I do not have authorization to perform `listKeys/action`. Heres my Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = local.default_tags
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "st_acc" {
  name                     = var.st_acc_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "ZRS"

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
  tags       = local.default_tags
}
```

This is the command I run to import the storage account:

```
terraform import -var-file=var.tfvars azurerm_storage_account.st_acc /subscriptions/<my-subscription>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<my-storage-acc>
```

This is the error I get:

```
│ Error: building Queues Client: retrieving Account Key: Listing Keys for Storage Account 
"<my-storage-acc>" (Resource Group "<my-resource-group>"): storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: 
Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: 
Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 
'<my-email>' with object id '<my-object-id>' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/<my-subscription>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<my-storage-acc>' 
or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
```

I have the `Reader` role in the subscription level, and the `Storage Account Key Operator Service Role` in the subscription level as well.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how should I resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixed by assigning the `Storage Account Contributor` role.
But I like to have a discussion here about whether there is a lower level role that lets you import a storage account into Terraform.

Or is this the least privilege level for that?